# Make a function accepting an optional to accept a non-optional?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, option-type, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to write syntactic sugar, in a monad-style, over `std::optional`. Please consider:

```
template<class T>
void f(std::optional<T>)
{}
```

As is, this function cannot be called with a non-optional `T`<sup>1</sup> (e.g. an `int`), even though there exists a conversion from `T` to `std::optional<T>`<sup>2</sup>.

**Is there a way to make `f` accept an `std::optional<T>` or a `T` (converted to an optional at the caller site), without defining an overload**<sup>3</sup>**?**

---

<sup>1)</sup> `f(0)`: `error: no matching function for call to 'f(int)'` and `note: template argument deduction/substitution failed`, ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/38d8f0787b1c871a)).
<sup>2)</sup> Because template argument deduction doesn't consider conversions.
<sup>3)</sup> Overloading is an acceptable solution for a unary function, but starts to be an annoyance when you have binary functions like `operator+(optional, optional)`, and is a pain for ternary, 4-ary, *etc.* functions.

Comment: have it take a T and then just check if it's an optional and if it's not, make it one.   constexpr if can do that super easy if you're using c++17.

Comment: @xaxxon that's worth an answer

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “in a monad-style”? Because as it stands your question suggests you are interested in some kind of automatic conversion or overload, and both answers do something along these lines. **But this has nothing whatsoever to do with monads**.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The mention of monads was just to give a context. I want, provided `F=λxy.`, an `optional(x)` and an `optional(y)`, return an `optional(F(xy))`. For such a definition to be useful and let its user chain expressions, it needs to accept both optionals and scalars.

Comment: The problem with this definition is that, unlike a monad, *it does not compose*. How would your function handle a `std::optional<std::optional<T>>`? Whereas if you had a monad lifting operator you would simply `lift(F)` and wouldn’t have this problem.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes. That's step two. I'm better fixing a problem at a time ;)

Comment: @YSC But if you have `lift` you don’t need this overload.

Comment: @KonradRudolph OK, I get it. I'm not sure I want to mimic haskel in all aspects though.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Another version. This one doesn't involve anything:

```
template <typename T>
void f(T&& t) {
    std::optional opt = std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

Class template argument deduction already does the right thing here. If `t` is an `optional`, the copy deduction candidate will be preferred and we get the same type back. Otherwise, we wrap it.

Comment: Even though this is not code golf, I've got the feeling this answer deserve the checkmark :D

Comment: Good line of thinking; however, doesn't opt need to be defined as std::optional<T> here?

Comment: @LThode Very much no.

Comment: @Barry -- a-ha, I see what you mean now -- I've never bumped into class template argument deduction before!

Comment: This lacks overload resolution features; is there a way to test if `std::optional opt = std::forward<T>(t)` would compile?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sure, test if `std::optional(std::declval<T>())` is a valid expression

Comment: `template<template<class...>class Z,  class...Ts>struct can_deduce:std::false_type{};` is, I guess, missing from `std`; I guess because there isn't a way to handle all template arguments (type and non-type) generically: `template<template<anything...>class Z, anything...Ts>`

Answer (score 15):

Instead  of taking optional as argument take deductible template parameter:

```
template<class T>
struct is_optional : std::false_type{};

template<class T>
struct is_optional<std::optional<T>> : std::true_type{};

template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<is_optional<std::decay_t<T>>::value>>
constexpr decltype(auto) to_optional(T &&val){
    return std::forward<T>(val);
}

template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<!is_optional<std::decay_t<T>>::value>>
constexpr std::optional<std::decay_t<T>> to_optional(T &&val){
    return { std::forward<T>(val) };
}

template<class T>
void f(T &&t){
    auto opt = to_optional(std::forward<T>(t));
}

int main() {
    f(1);
    f(std::optional<int>(1));
}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/4byieE)

Answer (score 14):

This uses one of my favorite type traits, which can check any all-type template against a type to see if it's the template for it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <optional>


template<template<class...> class tmpl, typename T>
struct x_is_template_for : public std::false_type {};

template<template<class...> class tmpl, class... Args>
struct x_is_template_for<tmpl, tmpl<Args...>> : public std::true_type {};

template<template<class...> class tmpl, typename... Ts>
using is_template_for = std::conjunction<x_is_template_for<tmpl, std::decay_t<Ts>>...>;

template<template<class...> class tmpl, typename... Ts>
constexpr bool is_template_for_v = is_template_for<tmpl, Ts...>::value;


template <typename T>
void f(T && t) {
    auto optional_t = [&]{
        if constexpr (is_template_for_v<std::optional, T>) {
            return t; 
        } else {
            return std::optional<std::remove_reference_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(t));
        }
    }();
    (void)optional_t;
}

int main() {
    int i = 5;
    std::optional<int> oi{5};

    f(i);
    f(oi);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/HXgoEE

Comment: Really nice trait you've got here. Do you know why `std::decay` is necessary?

Comment: @YSC Without `std::decay` it would not work automagically with types like `std::optional<int> &` and related ones

Answer (score 5):

Another version. This one doesn't involve writing traits:

```
template <typename T>
struct make_optional_t {
    template <typename U>
    auto operator()(U&& u) const {
        return std::optional<T>(std::forward<U>(u));
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct make_optional_t<std::optional<T>> {
    template <typename U>
    auto operator()(U&& u) const {
        return std::forward<U>(u);
    }
};

template <typename T>
inline make_optional_t<std::decay_t<T>> make_optional;

template <typename T>
void f(T&& t){
    auto opt = make_optional<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```