# C++ template function with std::optional

Tags: c++, templates, clang++

Attempting to use a template class inside of an optional i.e. `std::optional<T>` as a function parameter for a templated function that does the following. If the `std::optional<T> param` is truthy, then uses the `<<` operartor to write `param.value()` to a `std::ostringstream`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <optional>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
std::string send(int number, std::optional<T> param)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::to_string(number);

    if (param)
    {
        oss << " " << param.value();
    }

    return oss.str();
}

// Works just fine
// template<typename T>
// std::string send(int number, T param)
// {
    // std::ostringstream oss;
    // oss << std::to_string(number);

    // if (param)
    // {
        // oss << " " << param;
    // }

    // return oss.str();
// }


int main()
{
    std::cout << send(1, {3});
    return 0;
}
```

However, the code above throws

> error: no matching function for call to 'send'
>
> note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
>   std::string send(int number, std::optional param)

Compiler command

```
clang++ main.cc --std=c++17
```

I don't quite understand why the compiler cannot infer the template argument here. Even when I specifically instantiate the template for a specific type as such.

```cpp
template std::string send(int number, std::optional<int> param);
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757614/why-doesnt-my-template-accept-an-initializer-list%EF%BC%89

Comment: Trying to find a better dupe target.

Comment: better target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50031190/could-not-convert-from-brace-enclosed-initializer-list-to-std-tuple

Comment: I think I found a good one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51945067/make-a-function-accepting-an-optional-to-accept-a-non-optional

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Cool.  I've used it.

Comment: Yup. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!